# Question about 4:145

Tags: quran, tafseer

Linguistically seen, does 4:145 state that ALL hypocrites will be in the lowest level of jahannam?

I'm asking because there are better hypocrites and worse hypocrites. As example, one might be forced into it and is not the biggest hypocrite while another does it out of free will and is the leader of a group of hypocrites, and I doubt they would get the exact same punishment instead of perfect precise justice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who made such a distinction and named types of hypocrites?

Comment: There's no need to. I haven't heard of multiple types of muttaqin, but still, there are multiple levels in jannah. And I don't think that all people with taqwa get the exact same thing.

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer mine, if you want an answer you should add all helpful information instead of reacting uncooperative. There's no distinction between munaafiqeen known in the qur'an.. .

Comment: My question isn't about multiple types of hypocrisy but about if the ayah covers all munafiqeen or not.

Comment: Good I was wondering what made you distinguish between munafiqeen and wanted clarification.